# How can i grab string inside element

Tags: jquery, ajax

so i was wondering how can i grab the data inside an element and replace/insert that string into an element

jquery & ajax :

```
(function(){
    $("#requestsone li h3").load( "request.php h3#totalamountofrequest" );
    console.log("hello there");
})();
```

now what i want is to grab the data inside the **h3#totalamountofrequest** and replace that with **#requestsone li h3** without replace the elements but the data inside those elements.

after load :

```
<h3>
    <h3>somestring<h3>
</h3>
```

what i dont want it to output is an h3 tag within another h3 tag

Comment: use `$(element).text()` if you want to insert plain text inside it, if you have HTML elements to be inserted, use `$(element).html()`.

Comment: Can you show us both the relevant html and what the load returns?

Comment: the load returns the string but within that string it adds the element which is a h3 tag but adds it within another h3 element.

Comment: jQuery.append() could also be used, see the docs

Comment: @pc-shooter but it would append with element i want to grab the string only with no elements and insert into elements that are already in the page/html file

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$('#totalamountofrequest').text($('#requestsone li h3').text());
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BexpD/)

**EDIT:**

This is how to do it upon a return of the `.load` function:

```
(function(){
    $("#requestsone li h3").load( "request.php h3#totalamountofrequest", null, function () {
         $('#totalamountofrequest').text($('#requestsone li h3').text());
         console.log("hello there");
    });    
})();
```

Comment: how would i come about if i wanted to insert with .load()

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('h3#totalamountofrequest').html($('#requestsone li h3').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply grab it using following code

```
$("#id").text("Text you want to add");
```

or

```
$(".class").text("Text you want to add");
```

or

```
$("element selector").text("Text you want to add");
```

Comment: This will work, but this answer would be better with some explanation of the text function in jQuery and a link to the jQuery documentation.